How to Stop Windows Registry Settings from Reverting?
So I'm trying to set my Windows system language to En-US and encountered this post, which tells me to change the value of Default and InstallLanguage of \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language to 0409
After changing them in the Windows Registry Editor and rebooting as instructed, the Windows language didn't seem to have changed and although the value for Default has stayed as 0409, the value for InstallLanguage changed back to its original value of 0804.
The screen-shot below shows some information about my Windows version (19045.4780). Unfortunately, it's in Chinese (which is why I'm trying to change the language):

Apologies for the inconvenience this might have created.
I wonder if this problem occurs because Microsoft read the same post and decided to patch it to make sure you have to pay them if you wanna change your system default language... In that case I wonder if downgrading Windows to a previous version would help... Any suggestions?
---UPDATE---
Thank you for your replies. Someone suggested in the comments that I might not have installed my en-US package pack, but running the command dism /online /get-packages shows it successfully installed on my PC(see screenshot)
screenshot

It’s not possible to change the language on Single Language  editions of Windows. Downgrading will absolutely not help. You could simply upgrade to an edition where this restriction doesn’t exist

@Ramhound Sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to do this specifically without upgrading as that would cost 99 dollars and I'm planning to buy a new computer soon anyway so it won't be worth it. A lot of people replying to the post I've mentioned reported successfully switching language without paying after changing the windows registry settings, so I'm just trying to duplicate that.

Those same comments suggested that the only reason this suggestion worked is because "every install Windows supports the English language", which is an assumption I suspect is actually incorrect.

@Ramhound I'm assuming as long as the English language pack is "installed" it should be supported?

That is the problem: the language pack cannot be installed on Windows Single Language editions.  I also disagree that every edition, including Single Language editions of Windows from China, has built-in support for English.

@Ramhound running the dism /online /get-packages command shows it properly installed. See latest update to the question
